# Navigating to public folder in ejs

Tags: ejs

I am developing a website using ejs. I have a page let's say /X/Y
The problem is, when I use

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="png" href="images/logo.png" />
```

in Y, the href directs it to the "/x/images/logo.png". how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

it is fixed by putting "/" before the link